# Unet Syncing within AR Hololens

Tags: unity, c#, augmented-reality, unet, hololens

I am out of options. I have tried everything I could and no matter what I do, the Transforms don't sync up. I have had multiple solutions that worked in my test, non AR project, but once I put on the HoloLens, it doesn't work.
Here is what I did:

```
//PlayerObject that is spawned by the NetworkManager
//(obviously has Network Identity component)
public class ClientObject : NetworkBehaviour {
    public static ClientObject CurrentClient;

    private void Start() {
        if(isLocalClient) CurrentClient = this;
    }

    public void MoveObject(GameObject obj, Vector3 position) {
        Cmd_MoveObject(obj, position);
    }

    [Command]
    public void Cmd_MoveObject(GameObject obj, Vector3 position) {
        obj.transform.localPosition = position;
    }
}
```

And now the object that wants to get synced. It has a Network Transform with standard settings, a network identity and (obviously) no-one has authority since it doesn't get spawned:

```
public class AnObject : MonoBehaviour {
    public void IWasMoved() {
        /*
         * Someone Moved this object, either by dragging it or
         * clicking on one of it's arrows through the hololons.
         */

        Vector3 newPosition = (the new position i want this object to have);
        ClientObject.CurrentClient.MoveObject(gameObject, newPosition);
    }
}
```

That's what I have. The only thing different from the version that works on my PC without the HoloLens is that I don't set `localPosition = position`, but instead use `Translate(position)` (which is obviously the non local version);

I am tired of writing new code, building the project, having Visual Studio translate the code to C++, start my HoloLenses and test if it works, which takes over an hour every time I do so.

So: is there anything fundamentally wrong with my code? Again: it works on my test project just fine. I refuse to believe that it's the HoloLens's fault...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as i'm aware this has no solution. Apparently the hololens is incompatable with syncing objects that weren't spawned in Unet.
I took the long road and coded the entire backend of server and client communication since Unet is unable to handle it...
A pity.